# Discarding space or null character

Tags: javascript

Will be a simple question, but not for me :) .

I was going through this code :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<h1>My First JavaScript</h1>

<p>Please input a number.</p>

<input id="demo" type="text">

<script>
function myFunction()
{
var x=document.getElementById("demo").value;
if(x==""||isNaN(x)) /*?*/
    {
    alert("Not Numeric");
    }
}
</script>

<button type="button" onclick="myFunction()">Click Me!</button>

</body>
</html>
```

which will give an output like

[image: this]

Here in code we are checking if no value enterd,alert user ,by checking `if(x==""||isNaN(x))` . But if I enter a space character inside textbox, the check fails. What will be the way to check it?

PS : I am using chrome. And trim() not worked.

Comment: To check what? There are many definitions of *numeric*, and if you cast a whitespace-only string to a number it's `0` in javascript.

Comment: if null value is entered

Comment: What's "null value"? The `value` property of a text input is always a string, never `null`.

Comment: so if i press a space it will treat it as a string?

Comment: Sure, a space is a string value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try regular expression insted

```
function myFunction(){
    var x=document.getElementById("demo").value;
    if(!(/^\d+$/.test(x))) {
        alert("Not Numeric");
    }
}
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/bTBwS/)

Comment: That does only test for existence of a digit

Comment: @ACB `/^\d+$/` is a [regular expression](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions) it has a method `test` which will return `true/false` based on whether the passed argument satisfies the regular expression. `^\d+$` stands for a line which has only numeric characters.

Answer (score 1):

The trim from jQuery is convenient if you can use jquery.

$.trim('  any value   ');

Or you want to use only JavaScript, Use trim function to ignore white space. Even though new browser supports trim. i recommend to create a separate function to overcome browser compatibility issues.

create a function

```
function trim(this)
{
return this.replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g, '');
};
```

Then in your code snipped change the code as

```
var x=trim(document.getElementById("demo").value);
```

Comment: The OP does obviously *not* use jQuery

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest calling `trim` on `x` before checking if it's a number. `trim` will remove any spaces left and right of the content, if any.

```
var x=document.getElementById("demo").value;
x = x.trim();
```

Note that trim is not available in some older browsers. If you need to support them you can implement it yourself or use a library function like [`jQuery.trim`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.trim/).

You could also use this:

```
if(isNaN(parseInt(x)))
```

(Assuming your x is supposed to be an integer.)

Answer (score 0):

trim your input string

```
var x=document.getElementById("demo").value.trim();
```

Answer (score 0):

Newer browsers support a `string.trim` function. For broader coverage, you can use regular expressions to remove spaces, and then check for the length of the result. If it's greater than zero, then test for `NaN`.

Here is one way to trim:

```
function trim(stringToTrim) {
    return stringToTrim.replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g,"");
}
```

Test:

```
var myString = " hello my name is ";
alert("*"+trim(myString)+"*");
```

This kind of approach is suggested by the [experts at Mozilla](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/Trim).

Answer (score 0):

If you want to avoid using trim or regex, you can use the `parseFloat` command. To implement this, use `parseFloat(x)`, which will return `NaN` if x is a space or anything else that isn't a number.